# How to dynamically add a script to the page using watir-webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have some *.js script that I want to execute using watir-webdriver during my test runs. So the question is there any way to upload the script to the page using watir-webdriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `execute_script` method to add a script element with the src attribute as your js file. The method call would look like:

```
browser.execute_script(    
  "var the_script = document.createElement('script');
  the_script.setAttribute('src','your_script.js');
  document.head.appendChild(the_script);"
)
```

To see that it works, let us assume you have the page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="field" value="100">  
  </body>
</html>
```

If you try to execute jQuery on the page (the '$' in the script), an exception occurs because the page does not know what jQuery is:

```
field = browser.text_field
p browser.execute_script('return $(arguments[0]).val();', field)
#=> $ is not defined (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)
```

If you add the jQuery script file (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js), via `execute_script`, you will now be able to use jQuery:

```
browser.execute_script(    
  "var the_script = document.createElement('script');
  the_script.setAttribute('src','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js');
  document.head.appendChild(the_script);"
)

field = browser.text_field
p browser.execute_script('return $(arguments[0]).val();', field)
#=> "100"
```

Comment: Such a simple solution and it's just not came to my mind. Big thanks Justin.